# Kali Linux Nvidia repository error

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, nvidia

I have been updating packages on my Kali Linux and came to the issue that it can’t fetch any Nvidia packages, for example nvidia-detect:

```
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali  kali-rolling/non-free amd64 nvidia-detect 470.74-1
    404  Not found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Falied to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/non-free/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers/nvidia-detect_470.74-1_amd64.deb  404  Not found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I found out that there’s newer version than 470.74-1 but `sudo apt update` can’t download new list although it doesn’t show any errors. Nothing I tried helped (operated with `apt-…`, `add-apt-repository` and others)

How can I fix this issue to update drivers correctly?

Comment: could  you add the cdn for the new version manually to your _/etc/apt/sources.list_?

Comment: So what should I type to it?

Comment: have a look here: https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/nvidia-graphics-drivers - I can give you an example for postgresql on debian: _sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'_

Comment: Still don’t know what to do. What link should I set?

Comment: A simple [google-search](https://www.google.com/search?q=kali+linux+add+manually+to++%2Fetc%2Fapt%2Fsources.list&rlz=1C1GCEU_deAT821AT821&sxsrf=AOaemvIYc2aMsrhM3hgyUdTMHKupRMu6GA%3A1639668029769&ei=PVm7YbmoLrOD9u8PuLu_6AQ&ved=0ahUKEwj5utqzz-j0AhWzgf0HHbjdD00Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=kali+linux+add+manually+to++%2Fetc%2Fapt%2Fsources.list&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQ1wJY1wJg8wVoAXAAeACAAXWIAXWSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) will enlighten you..